# How can I pass a service principal password stored in vault to the az aks create --client-secret parameter

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-cli, azure-aks

I am unable to pass service principal password stored in the vault for az aks create --client-secret parameter

To Reproduce
1.) create a vault

```
az keyvault create \
    --name ${AZURE_VAULT_NAME} \
    --resource-group ${AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP} \
    --location ${AZURE_LOCATION} \
    --enabled-for-deployment 'true'
```

2.) create service principal account using vault

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac \
    --skip-assignment \
    --name ${AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME} \
    --create-cert \
    --cert ${AZURE_VAULT_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_KEY_NAME} \
    --keyvault ${AZURE_VAULT_NAME}
```

3.) output to az ad sp create shows as

```
{
  "appId": "d216c019-cd17-4350-a467-77be6e76c135",
  "displayName": "aksServicePrincipalPOC",
  "name": "http://aksServicePrincipalPOC",
  "password": null,
  "tenant": "06dd2342-6928-44d9-bd0f-bfb06b15a097"
}
```

Note password is null.

4.) create aks cluster using service principal. There does not appear to be a way to pass the secret or vault name for the az aks create command. I have no value to set --client-secret since it was not returned when creating service principal account.

```
az aks create \
    --resource-group ${AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP} \
    --name ${AKS_CLUSTER_NAME} \
    --admin-username ${AKS_NODE_ADMIN_USERNAME} \
    --node-count ${AKS_MIN_NUMBER_OF_NODES} \
    --service-principal ${AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL} \
    --client-secret ??????????? \
    --ssh-key-value ${AKS_VM_SSH_KEY_FILE_DIR}/${AKS_VM_SSH_KEY_FILE_NAME}.pub \    
    --network-plugin azure \
    --vnet-subnet-id ${AZURE_PRIVATE_SUBNET_ID} \
    --docker-bridge-address ${AZURE_AKS_DOCKER_BRIDGE_ADDRESS} \
    --dns-service-ip ${AZURE_AKS_DNS_SERVICE_IP} \
    --service-cidr ${AZURE_AKS_SERVICE_CIDR}
```

Expected behavior:
There should be an option with az aks create to have it pull the service principal password from the vault maintaining that secret.

Answer (score 0):

this wont work, as this creates a certificate auth for the service principal, not password auth (hence it not returning any password value).

because you are asking it to create a certificate auth enabled service principal.

Comment: How would you suggest this be done in a way that the nodes in the aks cluster are able to retrieve secrets from the vault without having to store the vault credential in some 3rd site for the aks node to pull it down to access the vault.

Comment: there is no way for AKS to pull any credentials from KV on its own. so I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here. your options are: service principal with password, nothing else. you cant create AKS cluster in any other way. if you want your pods to be able to pull secrets from KV, there are options like KV "adapter" for kubernetes and\or Managed Service Identity for worker nodes.

Comment: @4c74356b41 Tried this today (Jan 6, 2020) using terraform and it worked like charm. I was able to pass the service principal client ID and secret stored in keyvault successfully to AKS and it launched perfectly too.

Comment: what did you pass as a client secret? how did you pass the certificate? @vishal.k

Comment: @4c74356b41 No I didn't use certificate. I used service principal with password. The client ID was stored as a secret in keyvault and password was stored as a separate secret in the same keyvault. In terraform script I just referred to the secret's names and it worked. That's it. Even I didn't expect it to work but just wanted to try and see what is the o/p error. To my surprise it accepted and worked.

Comment: well, this question is about using an SP with a certificate...